# How do I change the Command Palette shortcut keybindings foreground text color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I change the text color below for the keyboard shortcuts **without** changing the base theme color to "vs-dark"?  I wasn't sure which one to use from the link below.  I realize some base colors aren't changeable yet via theme colors; however, I want to be certain.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

[image: Command Palette keybindings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are being added to v1.56.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_56.md#keybinding-label-colors

> #### New theme colors
>
> Keybinding label colors
>
> Keybinding labels are shown when there is a keybinding associated with
> a command. Usages of the keybinding label include (but are not limited
> to):
>
> - The Command Palette
> - The Keyboard Shortcuts editor
> - The Keyboard Shortcuts recorder modal
> - The "feature contribution" section of an extension's marketplace page
>
> The following customizations are available:
>
> - `keybindingLabel.background`: Keybinding label background color.
> - `keybindingLabel.foreground`: Keybinding label foreground color.
> - `keybindingLabel.border`: Keybinding label border color.
> - `keybindingLabel.bottomBorder`: Keybinding label border bottom color.

In your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "keybindingLabel.foreground": "#fff",     // text color
  "keybindingLabel.background": "#333"
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just verified that this is indeed implemented in the full non-Insider release of VSCode a couple of days ago.